# What is the object type of an anonymous class

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Please look at the Java classes below:

```
 class A {
   public void doProcess(){
      System.out.println("Process from A class!");
   }
 }
```

---

```
 class B extends A {
   @Override
   public void doProcess(){
      System.out.println("Process from B class!");
   }
 }
```

I have 2 classes as shown above. If I were to do the below (an anonymous class)

```
 new B() {
   @Override
   public void doProcess(){
      System.out.println("Process from Anonymous class");
   }        
 }
```

Am I creating new subclass of B? Or is it an instance of B?

I know I could assign the anonymous implementation to either B or A. What I wasn't sure is on the instance of the anonymous class that's created. More curios on what Java does than for any practical purposes. I don't know how to get the class object of this anonymous inner class to use some reflection API and figure that out myself.

Comment: Subclass of B..

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce. Can you also help me how to find myself (with a reflection API or something) that it's a sub class of B?

Comment: Why? It is. That's the meaning of the code you wrote.

Comment: @InfiniteLoop You can assign an instance of it to a variable of type B `B b = new B() { ...}`. And you can check that `b.getClass() != B.class` to see that it's not an instance of B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are creating an instance of an anonymous sub-class of class `B`.

```
B b = new B() {
   @Override
   public void doProcess(){
      System.out.println("Process from Anonymous class");
   }        
}
System.out.println (b.getClass ().getSuperclass ());
```

This will print

```
class some.package.B
```

where `some.package` is the package where class B is located.

Comment: Also: `b instanceof B` will evaluate to `true`, but `b.getClass().equals(B.class)` will evaluate to `false`.